# How to find adjoint operator in polynominal space equipped by integral inner product?

Tags: linear-transformations

Consider linear space of polynomials $P^{n}$, define inner product
$$
\langle p,q\rangle=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^{1}p(t)q(t)t^2dt 
$$
How can I find adjoint operator of
$$
S(p)(t)=p'(t)+2p(t)
$$
and
$$
T(p)(t)=tp'(t)-3p(t)
$$
I have two thoughts, (1) do matrix calculation, or (2) do integration by parts.

(1) I may find a common pattern of a matrix G for $\langle p,q\rangle=p^{T}Gq$, then for a linear transformation $M$ on $P^{n}$ I have
$$
(Mp)^{T}Gq=p^{T}GG^{-1}M^{T}Gq
$$
then, the adjoint of $M$ is
$$
M^{*}=G^{-1}M^{T}G
$$
However, for this approach, I don't know what pattern to find. Neither do I know how to express the pattern using a formula similar to those of $S$ and $T$.

(2) It might be possible to manipulate directly with the integral definition of $\langle p,q\rangle$ to find the adjoints. I have given it a few tries, but always ended up in clueless computation.

So how do I find the adjoints, is there a clean way to do this?

Comment: Use \langle and \rangle instead of < and >